# Cannot stack LSTM with MultiRNNCell and dynamic_rnn

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, multi-layer

I am trying to build a multivariate time series prediction model. I followed the following tutorial for temperature prediction. http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/addfor/tutorials/blob/master/machine_learning/ml16v04_forecasting_with_LSTM.ipynb

I want to extend his model to multilayer LSTM model by using following code:

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden, state_is_tuple=True)  
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell] * num_layers,state_is_tuple=True)  
output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=features, dtype=tf.float32)
```

but I have an error saying:

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 256 and 142 for
>   'rnn/while/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cell_0/lstm_cell/MatMul_1' (op:
>   'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,256], [142,512].

When I tried this:

```
cell = []
for i in range(num_layers):
    cell.append(tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden, state_is_tuple=True))
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cell,state_is_tuple=True)
output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=features, dtype=tf.float32)
```

I do not have such error but the prediction is really bad.

I define  `hidden=128`.

`features = tf.reshape(features, [-1, n_steps, n_input])` has shape `(?,1,14)` for single layer case.

my data look like this `x.shape=(594,14), y.shape=(591,1)`

I am so confused how to stack LSTM cell in tensorflow. My tensorflow version is 0.14.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. Initially, I thought that two codes produce the same output (*i.e* stacking two **LSTM cells**).

**code 1**

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden, state_is_tuple=True)  
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell] * num_layers,state_is_tuple=True)
print(cell)
```

**code 2**

```
cell = []
for i in range(num_layers):
    cell.append(tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden, state_is_tuple=True))
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cell,state_is_tuple=True)
print(cell)
```

However, If you print the **cell** in both instances produce something like following,

**code 1**

```
[<tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl.BasicLSTMCell object at 0x000000000D7084E0>, <tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl.BasicLSTMCell object at 0x000000000D7084E0>]
```

**code 2**

```
[<tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl.BasicLSTMCell object at 0x000000000D7084E0>, <tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl.BasicLSTMCell object at 0x000000000D708B00>]
```

If you closely observe the results,

- For **code 1**, prints a list of two **LSTM cell objects** and one object
  is the copy of other (since the pointers of the two objects are same)
- For **code 2** prints a list of two different **LSTM cell objects** (since the pointers of two objects are different).

Stacking two **LSTM cells** is something like below,

[image]

Therefore, If you think about the big picture (actual Tensorflow operation may be different), what it does is,

1. First map **inputs** to **LSTM cell 1** hidden units (in your case **14** to **128**).
2. Second, map hidden units of **LSTM cell 1** to hidden units of **LSTM cell 2** (in your case **128** to **128**) .

Therefore, when you trying to do the above two operations to the same copy of **LSTM cell** (since the dimensions of weight matrices are different), there is an error.

However, if you use the number of **hidden** units as same the number **input** units (in your case input is **14** and hidden is **14**) there is no error (since the dimensions of weight matrices are the same) although you are using the same **LSTM cell**.

Therefore, I think your second approach is correct if you are thinking of stacking two **LSTM cells**.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am still confused:

Comment: what are you confused about?

Comment: why the 1st map is 14(which is the dimension of my features) to 256(which is my batch size).

Comment: Sorry, should be 128 (which is your hidden) not 256.

Comment: I have a time series data: from t = 1 to 594, each data point has 14 features. If I want to build a 3-layer LSTM for prediction, should I set my data to have(None, 128, 14), the LSTM cell is (128) ? So that my LSTM network has length (128).And I can use the 1st method to stack LSTM.

Comment: I was having this same issue, but am not understanding the "best" solution. I see other people stack LSTMs that have different inputs and state sizes.